# Cycle through ALL open windows in ALL open applications? (keyboard shortcut?)

Tags: macos, finder, shortcut

We all know  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>    to switch apps, and  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>'</kbd>   to cycle though windows within an app, but…

… How to cycle through ALL open windows in ALL open applications? (keyboard shortcut?)

I knew this once, but forgot it. What is the key combo for this?

Answer (score 4):

There's  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>F4</kbd>  which is "Move focus to active or next window"… but it doesn't work across Spaces properly.

[image]

You could use <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch apps, and on the icon of the application you want to switch windows in press the down arrow key (with <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd> still pressed). Then use left/right keys to navigate to the desired window across spaces and desktops.

Comment: +1 for cmd+down after cmd+tab! lifesaver!